# 'Is Oracle a trustworthy source' (VirtualBox)?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I was installing VirtualBox and had to accept Oracle to have access to driver software and other components for example the USB drivers... Is that okay or should I uninstall it??

Answer (score 0):

I would say Oracle is trustful.

Quote from Wikipedia:

> "Oracle Corporation is an American multinational computer technology
>   corporation headquartered in Redwood Shores, California."

Furthermore if you don't accept the access to drivers, e.g. you won't be able to access an USB device from within your VM.

Answer (score 0):

That's OK, you shouldn't uninstall it.

VirtualBox uses access to hardware on your computer so that you can use e.g. DVD drive, USB ports etc. so - if you don't accept that, you won't be able to use any of these.